# zsh substitution, reverse subscripting (r flag), how to use regex

Tags: zsh

I want to parse argument in a ZSH sript with reverse subscripting. In the ZSH Guide, in chapter 5, "Substitutions", it seems from the examples that regex can be use : `print ${array[(r)s*]}`.I would like to assemble reverse subscripting with regex tests as in this example :

```
if [[ ${ARGS[(r)--opt=?.*]} =~ "--opt=?.*" ]] ; then
    # some stuff
fi
```

I have done tests and it seems that only the wild card character '*' works in reverse subscripting. The regex works here only for the "test" part. I use the zsh/regex module (POSIX extended regular expression).

Can regex be used with reverse subscripting with ZSH? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: That's not a regular expression; it's a pattern that matches `s` followed by 0 or more arbitrary characters. It does not match 0 or more `s`s.

Comment: Ok, there does not appear to be any possibility to use regex in reverse subscripting.